# Count the frequency that a status has been changed in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 7 statuses in the Sharepoint and I wish to track how many times an item has been returned to a certain status before it gets completed

example
pending
back for rework
completed

I want to count how many times an item has been returned to status "Back for Rework" before it gets completed (if the item was not approved the first time, then the item is sent to rework).

Comment: Changed by what/who? You need to add more details to your question.

Comment: Also, how do you intend to use this information? For example, Are you wanting to trigger some type of alert/email notification? Or design a view based on items that have been back for rework more than x times? Depending on your use case, there could be many different ways to implement this with varying degrees of complexity.